# Javascript: Cannot display image from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning javascript by building a quiz app. I have an array and each item in the array contains a question, image, options, answer. But I don't know how to display images to HTML. Please help me. Thank you.

html file:

```
    <div class="box" id="questionScreen">
        <div class="questionBox">
            What does HTML stand for?
        </div>

        <div class="iq" id="iqid">
            <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="optionBox">
            <span onclick="checkAnswer(this)" data-opt="1"></span>
            <span onclick="checkAnswer(this)" data-opt="2"></span>
            <span onclick="checkAnswer(this)" data-opt="3"></span>
            <span onclick="checkAnswer(this)" data-opt="4"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Quiz.js (array)

```
let quiz = [
{
    question: "What does HTML stand for?",
    image: "img/5.jpg",
    option: [
        "Hyper Tag Markup Language",
        "Hyper Text Markup Language",
        "Hyperlinks Text Mark Language",
        "Hyperlinking Text Marking Language",
    ],
    answer: 2,
},
{
    question: "What does CSS stand for?",
    image: "../img/6.jpg",
    option: [
        "Computing Style Sheet",
        "Creative Style System",
        "Cascading Style Sheet",
        "Creative Styling Sheet",
    ],
    answer: 3,
},
];
```

script.js (Function)

```
let index =0;
let attempt = 0;

let totalQuestion = questions.length;
function printQuestion(i) {
   $(".questionBox").text(questions[i].question);
   $(".optionBox span").eq(0).text(questions[i].option[0]);
   $(".optionBox span").eq(1).text(questions[i].option[1]);
   $(".optionBox span").eq(2).text(questions[i].option[2]);
   $(".optionBox span").eq(3).text(questions[i].option[3]);
   //How to display image property
}
```

Comment: something like `<img src=" +  questions[i].image + ">`?

Comment: Thanks Cid. But it doesnt work :(

Comment: Just set the `src` property of the image: `$('#iqid img').attr('src', questions[i].image);`

Comment: @ElChiniNet It shows error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Here's the error: https://imgur.com/rRkkaoR

Comment: Then your paths are wrong, add a prefix to the path with the location of your images.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's worked!!

Answer (score 0):

The images you have are paths to the image, as you might already know. So you'll need to tell html where the find these images, in an image tag.

where you use the image, like `<img src="img/myimage.png">` you'll need to programmatically loop through your array and create an `<img>` tag for each one.

something like this.

```js
let div_contains_images = $('.image_div')
for (let q of quiz){
   let image_element = $(`<img src="img/${q.image}">`)
   div_contains_images.append(image_element)
}

// -------------------------------------
// or for a single image in your use case

let image_number = 2
let image_path = quiz[image_number].img
$('#iqid > img').attr('src', image_path)
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It's still the same: it uses the image in the html to display, not the image in the array. It's neccessary that I remove the image source in html?

Comment: It should replace the `src` when you set in using jquery, however just make sure with your version of jquery, it could be `$().prop('src', src)`, `$().attr('src', src)`, `$().scr(src)` or even `$().src = src`

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I don't use jquery, I use js vanilla. So I should use jquery?

Comment: Oh my bad, there is jQuery in your question. If you want to use vanilla JS you might need to use `document.createElement('img')`and set the source using `element.src=src;`

Comment: `const img = document.createElemtent("img");` here's your advice. `img.src = currentQuestion.image; questionImage.appendChild(img);` after that I add 2 more lines. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. rather use `let`, and not `const`, because `let` allows you to modify the variable. `const` does not allow any changes

Comment: It's seem not understand what I want to do :(( this time I lost the answers: [link](https://imgur.com/rYx6YU4)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to loop through the `quiz` array, and prepare the html structure you want to create.

```js
let quiz = [
{
    question: "What does HTML stand for?",
    image: "img/5.jpg",
    option: [
        "Hyper Tag Markup Language",
        "Hyper Text Markup Language",
        "Hyperlinks Text Mark Language",
        "Hyperlinking Text Marking Language",
    ],
    answer: 2,
},
{
    question: "What does CSS stand for?",
    image: "../img/6.jpg",
    option: [
        "Computing Style Sheet",
        "Creative Style System",
        "Cascading Style Sheet",
        "Creative Styling Sheet",
    ],
    answer: 3,
},
];

function printQuestions(questions){
  let htmlString = '';
  questions.forEach(question => {
    // add question text
    htmlString += `<div class="questionBox">
            ${question.question}
        </div>`;
        
    // add the image
    htmlString += `<div class="iq">
            <img src="${question.image}" alt="">
        </div>`;
        
    let optionsString = '';
    question.option.forEach(option => {
      optionsString += `<span onclick="checkAnswer(this)" data-opt="1">${option}</span>`;
    });
    
    // add options to htmlString
    htmlString += `<div class="optionBox">${optionsString}</div>`;
  });
  
  // append htmlString to wrapping element
  $('#questionScreen').html(htmlString);
}//printQuestions()

// call the function we just defined
printQuestions(quiz);
```

```css
.questionBox
{
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.optionBox span
{
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="questionScreen">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit. It shows error when I press Play button.

Comment: @AnhKhoa I see the HTML generated when I click the `Run code snippet` button. It's only when you click one of the options that you get the error, and that occurs because the code doesn't include the `checkAnswer` function.